# how to return value from nested array - swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

My api query is returning several values in an array (as below), which I need to use for further functions. How do I retrieve the value 60, which is nested?

My code eg `let uid = value["uid"] as? String` works well to return uid and name. 
But for `let rest = value["field_resting_bpm"] as? String` it returns nil.

How do I correct this line to return the nested value '60'?:

```
 let rest = value["field_resting_bpm"] as? String'
```

the api query is:

```
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
```

var checkUserEndpoint: String = "https://example.site/ios1/user/1.json"

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, checkUserEndpoint, parameters: nil, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print("ran alamofire")
                //got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                print("no result data received when calling GET")
                return
            }
            // return UID
            print("ran alamofire")
            var datareturned = JSON(value)
            print("VALUE: \(value)")
```

it returns this in my console:

```
 uid = 1;
 name = "Guest User";
"field_resting_bpm" =     {
    und =         (
                    {
            value = 60;
        }
    );
```

UPDATE: this field is an Integer in Drupal user account settings. I have added a text field (so it should return a string), named field_rest_bpm_string, also for testing

the json on the site returns:

"field_resting_bpm":{"und":[{"value":"60"}]},"field_rest_bpm_string":{"und":[{"value":"65","format":null,"safe_value":"65"}]}

Comment: Check your structure first. `field_resting_bpm` is a dictionary and it has an array `und` in which the first object has a key value  named as "value" and value is 60

Comment: Good tip, thank you. Just checked and in my Drupal7 site, this field is in my user accounts, with a field type Integer. I am trying options to change the code suggested to Int, no luck so far. I will try also changing the field in the Drupal user settings, to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: Code is in Swift 3 but you can easily convert that in swift 2. `SwiftyJSON` version code is same in 2 and 3.

If you are using `SwiftyJSON` then things are pretty much simpler

```
let value = datareturned["field_resting_bpm"]["und"][0]["value"].stringValue
print(value)
```

If you are not using `SwiftyJSON`

```
let rest = value["field_resting_bpm"] as? NSDictionary
let und = (rest?.value(forKey: "und") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
let yourValue = und.value(forKey: "value") as! String
```

Something like this.

Comment: In Swift it is batter to use native Dictionary and Array instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`

Comment: true... But I prefer using `SwiftyJSON`. Also sometimes native depends on the needs. Here there is a reference, for swift array we are using values i.e struct

Comment: I'm talking about `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` not `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I am using SwiftyJSON (and have 'import SwiftyJSON' at the top of the file) so I have tried that first. The result:  XCode ran red errors about optional values until I had added these ! and the code was this:   'let rest = value["field_resting_bpm"]!!["und"]!![0]["value"]!!.stringValue'       But Then it returned nil and crashed.  Any ideas?

Comment: When trying the code not using SwiftyJSON and using NSDictionary, on the line beginning 'let und =' I am getting the red error "value of type NSDictionary has no member value".  Thoughts?

Comment: I am a beginner so may be on the wrong track totally but I wonder is it perhaps that the name "field_resting_bpm" is surrounded by " " in the array, whereas for name and uid they are not? Does this affect the code?   Writing it as value[""field_resting_bpm""] does not work though.

Comment: @NiravD I got it already. I was talking about third parties to handle such things like object mappers for ex swiftyjson which handles itself get it typecasted.

Comment: @DimitriT Can you provide your get API to me, so that I can see the issue

Comment: Thank you, sure -I will add it to the question above too. Here it is: 
                Alamofire.request(.GET, checkUserEndpoint, parameters: nil, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print("ran alamofire")
                    //got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    print("error calling GET")
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }

Comment: it is  var checkUserEndpoint: String = "https://example.site/ios1/user/\(uidEntered!).json"   That is https before the site name (on stack exchange it is removing the value). I can give you the site link if needed (I think on StackOverflow they prefer we write example.site)

Comment: @DimitriT what is the value for `uidEntered`. I want the complete URL that you can enter in your browser or postman to see the json

Comment: @DimitriT its asking for authentication. Also what are the headers you are passing

Comment: I have just edited them, so that I can share them for testing:  for user1, it is now WD as name, Cpass as pass.  I have basic auth headers. (Have updated the q above). The header code is let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari thank you so much for your solution. I wanted to retrieve a value from nested JSON dictionary. I used (let accessToken = parseJSON.value(forKeyPath: "Data.Token") as? String) but it turns to nil when I was using (as? String). Now with your solution I could get the String value.